# Passing list to sc.textFile -scala-

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark

I'm looking for how to pass a list of paths to `sc.textFile` (in scala), without using `foreach`.

Example :

`myList :Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer (path1, path2, path3)`

Is there a way to do :

`var data = sc.textFile(myList)`

Comment: There is no such thing. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var data = sc.textFile(myList.mkstring(","))
```

Alternatively, we can read each text file, then `union` the resulting rdds:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success}

val rdds = myList.flatMap { f =>
  Try(sc.textFile(f)) match {
    case Success(rdd) => Some(rdd)
    case _ => None
  }
}
val rdd = sc.union(rdds)
```

Comment: that may work because the way `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf` is used in Spark. But I do not think that is is recommended to use this.

Comment: Oh, hang-on, it might be that CSV style might only work for directories as opposed to file paths..

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Please can you provide a reference so that we can make an informed decision?

Comment: It worked. Thank you. One last question : How to add the try/catch exception that skip if a folder in the path is empty ?

Comment: Hmm I think we just found why @SarveshKumarSingh advised not to use this approach :) Unless appending wildcard to directory paths solves this, it might be that we need a different approach?

Comment: hmm, I will think of some solution for this and go back to you if any. Thanks

Comment: Ok np. I've edited answer to add example of unioning multiple rdds. Sorry didn't have time to test it, but hopefully will help